# Storing and retrieving distinct sounds in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have an idea for a iOS app. Before learning the development framework, would like to check if the basic concept is feasible. In order to work, the app would need to store a collection of sounds, which could be matched to sounds a user pronounces. Although these sounds are not regular words, the analogy to words is valid.

So, the app would need to:

- Record a sound or word, and store them as objects in a collection or
  map.
- When a user pronounces a word, retrieve the correct object from the map.

Obviously, applications like Siri which recognize words essentially do something similar, of course on a way more sophisticated level. But could the basic functionality be implemented by a mortal developer like myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could the basic functionality be implemented by a mortal developer like myself?

Yes! Without 3rd-party library, even. Since iOS 13 and macOS 10.15, Apple add [MLSoundClassifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/createml/mlsoundclassifier), with it, you can record multiple samples, tag them appropriately, then train and get the  Core ML model. This file can be reused on other macOS and iOS devices. [SoundAnalysis](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/soundanalysis?language=objc) will then use the model to determine the category of the new sound you feed into it. You can even enable the user to give a feedback of the detection accuracy & add the new sound to the training set, thus improving the model quality further.